# How assign a webpage to a letter in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

When I write an alphabet in the Chrome search bar then usually some website from the History shows up which is good if that page is what you want but bad otherwise.

I want this: I type the letter e and let's say the webpage examppllee.com/blabla shows up. It is likely that examppllee.com/blabla is from my history. Suppose I want that only examppllee.com to show up without the /blabla extension. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Visiting the *example.com/* webpage directly would list that hit alphabetically before any subsequent pages on that site.  But it won't stop you seeing *eatmorecake.com* first...

Comment: I solved the problem by erasing my history and then copy paste the example.com in 5 or more tabs so that Chrome stored that as my favorite site starting with the letter e. I guess more elegant ways exists.